# Why didn't Hannah Baker ask for Tony's help?

Tags: plot-explanation, 13-reasons-why

In the last episode of *13 Reasons Why*, Hannah decided to go talk with Mr.  Porter, because she wanted to give life one last chance. We know what happened next, so, for those who don't, I don't want to spoiler anything.

One doubt comes in my mind. Why didn't Hannah try to ask Tony to help her? Tony looks like the kind of guy who already knows what he wants and who always tries to do the right thing. I'm pretty sure that one guy with this personality would have helped Hannah to solve all her problems, while still alive.
Actually she chooses to, but she still kills herself, without waiting for Tony's help.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the things that is often mentioned (especially once Clay starts asking questions) is that *any* of the 13 could have stopped Hannah. Hannah only died because **all** of her safety nets failed to work at the same time.

*(Note: I personally disagree with that basic premise; but I am explaining it as it was intended in the show)*

Imagine Hannah going skydiving and having 13 parachutes with her. If all 13 fail and she falls to the ground; you could point to any of the parachutes and say that their failure to open is the reason Hannah died. But you'd be missing the point that Hannah's life didn't just hinge on the action of one parachute (person), but all of them combined.

Comment: I understand this, and thank you for your answer. What I don't understand - and maybe I wasn't that clear in my question - is: why didn't Hannah use Tony as a 14th parachute? (or 12th, since she said she wanted to give the 13th a last chance)

Comment: That is where I disagree with the premise of the show. For the show's plot, Hannah needed to stay close to Tony so that he could oversee what happened with the tapes. She didn't want to "test" their friendship because that means it could fall through and then he wouldn't want to do the tape thing anymore. But Hannah's life indeed could have been saved if she had talked to Tony, and it was ridiculous to not try. This means that Hannah needed Tony more for the tapes than for her own life and wellbeing, and that turns Hannah's actions into those of an intentionally angsty teenage drama queen.

Comment: That's my opinion too. If she would have cared more about her life and about her being fine, she should have talked to Tony. She knew he was a good guy, because she sent him the tapes, knowing he would have accomplished the job. It's like she cared more about this idea of the tapes, rather than her well-being and that's not a very deep message in my honest opinion.

Comment: Even disregarding Tony, the same still holds true in my opinion. Hannah (on the tapes) clearly shows that she knows most of the 13 were oblivious to how they wronged Hannah (or didn't see Hannah's side) and would have wanted to make amends _if only they knew_. This is **especially** true of Clay's tape, when she even says that he did not actively wrong her! Yet Hannah never gives them the chance to make amends. (This was the main reason why I was fearing a season finale of "Hannah's not dead after all and everyone now loves her!").

Comment: I think this is the main message of the series. I think that at that age in that environment, is very difficult to utter personal feelings, especially if one (Hannah) is ashamed of them.The risk is that you will not be taken seriously or at least as serious as you would like. I thought Hannah recorded those tapes to be taken seriously. I don't think that the 12 (not Clay) guys would have taken her into that consideration if she would just have said that. This is especially true in Mr. Porter's case, but I think it applies to everyone else, except, indeed, Tony.